# Resolving a promise

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to find if a message in a channel still exists, however, I am not sure how I resolve the promise, looking at other answers and the documentation I can see that it is probably via a function, but I am not entirely sure on how to do it. I would appreciate some help on this one, as it's the last step to a new feature on my Discord bot.

```js
    const embedId = embedChannel.messages.fetch(foundtEmbed.ticketembedchan);
```

`console.log(embedId)` currently outputs `Promise { <pending> }`

Comment: You don't have to resolve that promise yourself. It will fulfill on its own when the value has been fetched. What is your job is to *wait* for it. Use `.then()` or `await` for that.

Comment: You need to wait for it, use `asyn/await` or `embedChannel.messages.fetch(foundtEmbed.ticketembedchan).then((res) => {}).catch((err) => {})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `async/await` or use `then`:

```
try {
  const embedId = await embedChannel.messages.fetch(foundtEmbed.ticketembedchan);
  console.log(embedId)
}catch(err) {
  console.log(err)
}
```

Don't forget to add `async` to your function.
or:

```
embedChannel.messages.fetch(foundtEmbed.ticketembedchan)
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```